# YouTube Java API returms null for all userprofileentry (ies) age, gender except location

Tags: youtube-api, user-profile

I tried to rerum some YouTube java API requests to gather userprofileentry (ies) for comments and noticed that age and gender are now returning null for all users except location. Apologies if this has been answered already, I would very much appreciate if someone can redirect me.

This is the code I user with the YouTubeService initialised with a devKey and ID ans was working OK a couple of months ago (even after some changes took places e.g. video tags removed).

```
UserProfileEntry userProfileEntry = YouTubeService.getEntry(new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/" + UserID), UserProfileEntry.class);

System.out.print("  "+userProfileEntry.getAge());
System.out.print("  "+userProfileEntry.getGender());
System.out.print("  "+userProfileEntry.getLocation());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information was recently removed from the YouTube web interface for a channel page, and it was then removed from the Data API responses.